# Updating a tuple of tuples

Tags: python, tuples, python-2.x

I have

`tuples = (('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('d',))`

I tried to update it with the following code.

```
for tup in tuples:
    tup += (1,)
print tuples
```

I expected the result will be `(('a',1), ('b',1), ('c',1), ('d',1))`. But it printed the same as the original value. Why?
When I inserted `print tup` in the loop, I saw that `tup` was updated.

Comment: tuples are immutable

Comment: Tuples are immutable and thus not updatable. Create a new one instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because tuples are immutable. `tup += (1,)` will return a new tuple with which you do nothing in your loop.

That being said, here you go:

```
>>> tuples = (('a',), ('b',))
>>> tuple(tup + (1,) for tup in tuples)
(('a', 1), ('b', 1))
```

Comment: Given that the OP needs to have something that's mutable, I think you should've suggested the use of mutable objects, such as lists...

Answer (score 2):

tuples are immutable, you can't update it but you can build a new one.

```
>>> l = (('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('d',))
>>> tuple((i[0],1) for i in l)
(('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1), ('d', 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have already noted, tuples are immutable. Therefore, they cannot be modified. If you need mutability to allow modification, then you should use a `list` instead.

```
>>> # tuples; immutable
>>> tt = ((1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3))
>>> tt
((1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3))
>>> for e in tt: e += (4, )
...
>>> tt
((1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3))

>>> # lists; mutable
>>> ll = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
>>> ll
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
>>> for e in ll: e += [4]
...
>>> ll
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

As shown above, if you use `list`s, you should be able to get what you want.